# Display Haar features from a trained AdaBoost classfier

Tags: opencv, classification, adaboost, haar-wavelet

Is there a way to display visually which Haar features are used at every stage of the classifier?

I have recently trained a classfier to detect vehicles, using opencv_traincascade.exe.
For further analysis, I would like to see the features being evaluated at every stage.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

It will be great if anyone can supply information about the cascade.xml, what are the meaning of the nodes.
Thanks

Comment: have a look at the answer here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/7784/cascade-classifier-data-structure/

Comment: @berak, so it's not supported in cv2? CvHaarClassifierCascade seems to be a cv1 API